# invalid frame size while using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying scale and convert a video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -s 1920×1080 output.mp4
```

But every time it shows error (Windows):

```
Invalid frame size: 1920├ù1080.
```

or on Linux:

```
Invalid frame size: 1920×1080.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `x`, not `×`.

- Incorrect: `1920×1080`
- Correct: `1920x1080`

Comment: I had copy-pasted framesize from another app, ran into exactly this issue but didn't realize it until I saw this post. Thanks :)

Comment: I was about to become mad. You saved my day. no. my week!! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. I copied from Finder and thought I was going insane.

Comment: THIS IS SAVIOUR OF OUR LIFE!

Answer (score 0):

Also, it cannot be a double, eg 512.0. Make sure it's an int 512.